# Mongo performance

Tags: performance, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

Our test tool creates n threads and execute m iteration inside each thread. 
We calculate min, avg and max operation time.
 So that we see from time to time mongo executes request extremely slow - up to few seconds.
Also each time first operation are slowest,  we even exclude it intentionally from statistics
and still difference between avg and max is huge. Is it normal? Can I eliminate those slow operations? Why mongo executes some of requests so extremely slow?

Below results for single operations mode and mix mode when we run simultaneously tests for insert/get/remove/update. In mix mode thread=1 means we created 4 threads one for each type of test
[image: Mongo performance test]

We used default value - 100 connections per host

Source

```
public void storeMt(MyTestObject myTestObject) {
    mongoTemplate.insert(myTestObject );
  }

  public MyTestObject getMt(long id) {
    MyTestObject result = mongoTemplate.findById(id, MyTestObject.class);
    return result;
  }


@Document
public class MyTestObject implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  private long id;
//class contains 20+ fields
.......
```

Comment: Did you write the exact same test as you linked to?  Their code is doing large batch inserts which should perform very well. More importantly, what's your question?

Comment: Actually no. My code is written in java, I created many threads and inserting  documents one by one. But still I think performance should be much better and without delay up to 10 seconds for some random operation. Is it ok or no? maybe i have to configure mongodb properly

Comment: If you're going to compare performance, you'd need to do the same operations. Without a lot more details about configuration, hardware, network, etc., it's hard to say if you're getting #s that make sense.

Comment: Ok you are right. Forget about comparing. I just made test and see some of operations were really slow. Is it ok? I just installed mongodb without any specific configuration

Comment: There's not too much for configuration. It's all documented. You need to put it on fast disks, give it enough memory for your working set, configure network, etc.

Comment: ok thx. We will check performance on staging version with 32Gb RAM

Comment: You'll need to read this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-performance/ (and the pages it links to) if you haven't already.

Comment: ok but what about select? it has the same issue

Answer (score 5):

I see few reasons why this may be happening.

1. It is not due to mongoDB it may be due to the java process. It takes time in the beginning to start and load(allocate memory) relevant variables in memory.
2. Use MMS, a monitoring tool for MongoDB to see if the database is a bottleneck. You can check the locks on database, network usage, memory usage.
3. MongoDB acquires lock on database level for the current version. And so if your query is hitting the same database (different or same collection of a single database), it may slow down the operation.
4. Also, adding more number of threads not necessarily increase the performance. It may bring down the performance due to extra load on CPU,Memory(RAM) etc. So, I suggest increase number of thread after frequent interval and then see when the performance stops improving.

I am sure if you do this, you will find out the exact reason why it is slowing down.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an expected behavior, whenever a query is executed, the  (winning) query plan is cached for further retrieval.

That query cache is also getting dumped time and again so occasionally it takes longer.

In your case some query seems costly, I think you need to identify those queries and take measures to enhance the performance, If it's a read query, maybe a (compound) index is needed.

If it's a write query, it would need further analysis, what sort of collection it is? what indexes it has and what's the count of documents?

Here is more on [query plan caching](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/)